# Filtros con selects, no me devuelve bien los valores

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buenas estoy haciendo una sección de filtros para sacar los resultados de las viviendas que correspondan a esos filtros. Lo primero que estoy haciendo es que según que tipo de inmueble selecciono, me muestre unos campos diferentes para filtrar.

**ESTO ES EL SELECT DEL HTML**

```
            <h3>Tipo de inmueble</h3>
              <div class="field contPMarg">
                <select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="tipo-vivienda"  name="estado" style="border:none;">
                  <?php
                  $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tipos");
                  foreach ($results as $tipos){
                  ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $tipos['tipo'] ?>"><?php echo $tipos['tipo'] ?></option>
                 <?php } ?>
                </select>
              </div>
```

UNA PARTE DE LA FUNCIÓN JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){
  $("#tipo-vivienda").on("change", function(e){
    var tipo = $('select[id=tipo-vivienda]').val();// capturar el inmueble selecionado.
    var datos = {
      'tipo-inmueble' :  tipo,
      'accion' : 'cargar-html-filtros'
    }
      actualizar(datos);

  });

 function obtenerFiltrosVivenda(){
    // obtengo el precio y todos los valores para el filtro de vivienda.
    var id ="";
    var datos = {
          'tipo': id
          //Aquí hay más datos pero no los pongo ya que no son necesarios para esto
    }
    return datos;
  }

 function actualizar(datos){
    $.ajax({
          url: "filtros.php",
          type: "post",
          dataType: "html",
          data: datos,
          success: function (resultado){
            $("#filtrado").html(resultado);
          }
        });
  }
  });
```

FILTROS PHP.

```
if($a == 'cargar-html-filtros'){
$tipo = $_POST['tipo-inmueble'];
// realizar consultas a la bd si es necesario,
//construir el html segun el tipo.
if($tipo == 'Viviendas'){
    $html = "
<h3 style=\"margin-top: 8%;\">Tipo contrato</h3>
    <div class=\"field contPMarg\">
  <select class=\"ui fluid dropdown\" name=\"estado\" style=\"border:none;\">
        <option value=\"\">Todos</option>"; // Aquí termina el primer bloque del $html
        $consulta = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM estado"); // Creo la consulta SQL
        $listaEstados = $consulta->fetch_array(); // Obtengo el resultado de la consulta SQL
            foreach ($listaEstados as $fila){ // Recorro la lista de estados
                $nombreEstado = $fila['estado']; // Obtengo el nombre del estado
                $estadoId = $fila['estado_id'];

            $html .="<option value=\"$estadoId\">$nombreEstado</option>"; // Lo concateno al HTML de respuesta.
          }
    $html .="
```

Hay más contenido pero muestra otras cosas que no tienen nada que ver con esto.

El problema es que el foreach me devuelve unos datos que no corresponden a lo que tiene que salir.

Tenia que salir: Alquiler, Alquiler con opción a compra, venta, traspaso.
Y lo que sale:

1,1,A,A,2,2,2,2 (esto en un select)

Alguna sugerencia??? gracias

Comment: Revisa la tabla estados y que tienes en ella, así como cual es la columna que contiene el nombre.

Comment: Eso esta correcto, lo trae `estado`@Xerif